# Memory usage of Google App Engine instance

Tags: google-app-engine, memory

I am developping an application using App Engine to collect, store and deliver data to users.
During my tests, I have 4 data sources which send HTTP POST requests to the server every 5s (all requests are exactly uniform).
The server stores received data to the datastore using Objectify.

At the beginning, all requests are manage by 1 instance (class F1) with 0.8 QPS, a latency of 80ms and 80MB of memory.
But during the following hours, the used memory increases and goes over the limit of F1 Instance.
However, the scheduler doesn't start another instance. When I stop all traffic, average memory never decreases.
Now I have 150MB memory instead of 128MB (limit of F1 class) and I stopped all the traffic.
I Tried to set performance settings manually or automatic, disable Appstats without any improvement.

I use Memcache and datastore, don't have any cron or task queues and the traffic is always the same.
What are the possible reasons the average memory increase?
Is it a bug of the admin console?

Which points define the quantity of memory used per request?

Another question:
Does Google have special discount for datastore read/write ( >30 million ops / day ) ?

Thank you,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the special price, I don't think there is. If your app needs this amount of read/write quota you should look into optimizing to minimize write and perhaps implement some sort of bulk writing if possible.

On the memory issue. You should post your code in order to get a straight answer since there are too many things to look into when discussing memory usage. Knowing more about your case will help in producing a straight answer.

Cheers,
Kjartan